# Windows Server CVE-1999-0527: Fix?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ftp, cve

Anyone know why I am getting this on a server Win 2012 R2?

FTP is not an enabled feature, on the server. It's a very old CVE and very (no) info about it on searching.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms99-039.aspx (1999)

Comment: may be false positive!

Comment: what's reporting it?

Comment: Global security report, which I have no input into